# How to return when my data is true once times

Tags: javascript, json

My purpose is comparison data and combine .
When my data is similar combine must return something.

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA","Q3":"BBB"};  
var combine = [{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

var num = combine.length;
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var Keys = Object.keys(combine[i]);
  Keys.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.length > 1) {

      console.log(element, data[element], combine[i][element]);

      if ((data[element] == combine[i][element])) {
        console.log("same");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And you will see the data has 3 and combine has 2 because i 
just want to compare just Q1, Q5 `(remake in var Keys = Object.keys(combine[i]); )`

 or you has another ways to help please tell me.

more example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeZQU.png)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: *return something* is not really somthing to return, right? please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: You want to check if any item in `combine` has the same value for  `Q1` and `Q5` as `data`? As it's written, it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I add more example now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if at least one item in `combine` which has all the properties in it same as `data`

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA","Q3":"BBB"}; 
    
var combine = [{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

var exists = combine.some(function(c){
  const keys = Object.keys(c);
  return keys.every(key => c[key] === data[key])
});

console.log(exists ? "same" : "not same")
```

If you want to get the first item from `combine` which matches the condition, then use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `some`

```js
var data = {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA","Q3":"BBB"}; 
    
var combine = [{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"},{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"Japan"}];

var match = combine.find(function(c){
  const keys = Object.keys(c);
  return keys.every(key => c[key] === data[key])
});

console.log(match)
```

Comment: But my service not always be Q1 and Q5. That's why i try to use  var Keys = Object.keys(combine[i]); and forEach

Comment: @BBBBeloved now it checks for every key in `combine[i]`

Comment: If i need the JSON of combine[0](combine position has same with data is possible?) and thank for your help

Comment: @BBBBeloved then you don't need the `some` wrapper. Just: `const keys = Object.keys(combine[0]); var exists = keys.every(key => combine[0][key] === data[key])`

Comment: Where I must edit? Can you edit in your Code please?

Comment: @BBBBeloved remove the entire `some` code. Everything except `console.log`

Comment: They said : combine is not a function.  var exists = combine(function(c){ ... });

Comment: @BBBBeloved When did i ever mention to use `combine` as a function? If you want to check just for first item in combine:  `var data= {...}; var combine = [...]; var keys = Object.keys(combine[0]); var exists = keys.every(key => combine[0][key] === data[key]); console.log(exists ? "same" : "not same")`. That's it.

Comment: No i mean whatever position is same return JSON data look like this {"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"} if not same at all return false or not same... I'm sorry if i make you get wrong.

Comment: @BBBBeloved if there is a match, you want to get the matched item from `combine`?

Comment: Yes if there is a match. i need JSON data match from combine too.

Comment: @BBBBeloved you want *all the matches* in an array or just the *first matched object*?

Comment: Just one (only item match in combine).I mean just first matches with data

Comment: @BBBBeloved updated the answer. `some` returns a boolean. Just checks if it exists or not. `find` returns the first item which matches the condition. `filter` returns multiple items which match a condition

Comment: Your are be kind thank for your help. I find the way so long.

Comment: @BBBBeloved you're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue. If you had mentioned your expected output as `{"Q1":"Male","Q5":"USA"}` in the question itself, this would have been resolved in 5 minutes. Please add the expected output to question next time :)